# Why isn't my prop styling for react component child applying?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've created a slider with icons based off of [mui slider][https://mui.com/material-ui/react-slider/] using props to add icons if desired by the user but my 'fill: red' property is not rendering on the icons leftSliderIcon and rightSliderIcon in localhost - I am targeting icons with the .MuiSvgIcon-root class selector. All the other class styling I've done below is working and I've tried other stackoverflow solutions to this issue to no avail. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Slider as MuiSlider, SliderValueLabelProps as MuiSliderValueLabelProps, SliderProps as MuiSliderProps, Box } from '@mui/material';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import {InputRangeSliderProps} from '../InputRangeSlider';

export function ContinuousIconSliderStyled(props: InputRangeSliderProps) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<number>(30);

  const handleChange = (event: Event, newValue: number | number[]) => {
    setValue(newValue as number);
  };

  const SliderStyled = styled(MuiSlider)<MuiSliderProps>(({ theme, color }) => ({
    height: 2,
    width: 100,
    ...(color === "primary" && {
      color: theme.colors.main.fillCtaPrimarySolidDefault,
      '& .MuiSlider-valueLabel': {
        color: theme.colors.main.fillCtaPrimarySolidDefault
      },
      // this styling below is not working
      '& .MuiSvgIcon-root': {
        fill: 'red',
      },
    }),
    ...(color === "secondary" && {
      color: theme.colors.main.borderSecondaryEnabled,
      '& .MuiSlider-valueLabel': {
        color: theme.colors.main.borderSecondaryEnabled
      },
    }),
    '& .MuiSlider-track': {
      border: 'none',
    },
    '& .MuiSlider-thumb': {
      height: 12,
      width: 12,
      '&:focus, &:hover, &.Mui-active, &.Mui-focusVisible': {
        boxShadow: '1',
      },
      '&:before': {
        display: 'none',
      },
    },
    '& .MuiSlider-valueLabel': {
      lineHeight: 1.2,
      fontSize: 12,
      padding: 0,
      width: 32,
      height: 32,
      borderRadius: '50% 50% 50% 0',
      transformOrigin: 'bottom left',
      transform: 'translate(50%, -100%) rotate(-45deg) scale(0)',
      '&:before': { display: 'none' },
      '&.MuiSlider-valueLabelOpen': {
        transform: 'translate(50%, -100%) rotate(-45deg) scale(1)',
      },
      '& > *': {
        transform: 'rotate(45deg)',
      },
    },
  }));

  return (
    <Box sx={{ margin: 3 }}>
      <Stack spacing={2} direction="row" sx={{ mb: 1 }} alignItems="center">
        {props.leftSliderIcon}
        <SliderStyled 
          aria-label="slider-component" 
          valueLabelDisplay="auto"
          value={/*this number changes thumb position*/ 50} 
          onChange={handleChange} 
          color={props.color}
        />
        {props.rightSliderIcon}
      </Stack>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your icons are outside your `SliderStyled` component so targeting them from inside your `SliderStyled` will not work. A possible solution is to style them from the `Stack` component.

```js
<Stack
  spacing={2}
  direction="row"
  alignItems="center"
  sx={{
    mb: 1,
    "& .MuiSvgIcon-root": {
      fill: "red",
    },
  }}
>
  ...
</Stack>
```

Comment: That works if I want to have hard coded values, but this solution will not work for me as I need to assign the primary and secondary values to it

Comment: You will have access to your `props.color` in the `Stack` you can use this in the same way you're doing when making the `StyledSlider`. The `sx` prop is also able to access your theme, see these [docs](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/#palette) for more information about that.